# fix 302 error in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

in my project I am redirecting user to another page on clicking a link.It is working fine in firefox and chrome but on ie it is showing a 302 status and it not redirecting to other page.How should i resolve this issue.

```
  <a title="Go toCompany" style="background: none!important" href='<%= Url.Action("XYZ","BuildingProject",new {id=item.Id})%>'>
```

Onclicking the above code ,

```
  public ActionResult XYZ(int id)
    {

        Helpers.SessionHelper.SetSession(id);
        BuildingProjectRepository p = new BuildingProjectRepository();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");

    }
```

and user is redirected to the index page.

Comment: 302 is a status code indicating a redirect not an error.

Comment: Please. Elaborate... :-D

Comment: Don't most traditional links redirect a user to another page?

Comment: Can you elaborate on 'it not redirecting to other page'? What do get instead? Also what version of IE? It may be a browser issue. You may want to use Fiddler to have a deeper look at what the issue may be.

Comment: it is ie8.There are 2 link on the page.what is happening is onclicking the first link it redirecting well and on clicking the second link it is also redirecting well.If i repeat i do this clicks repeatdely then on clicking thses links it is not redirecting to proper page but showing a status 302.